# Excel formula to find data based on header text and check if data is missing

Tags: search, text

[Snapshot of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoqEW.png)
The data table per snapshot can be anywhere in columns A:K and could also be starting at a different row. Also, the number of entries (rows 35 to 45 in the snapshot example) in that table can vary.

I'd like to add a formula that detects if data is missing (B42) or not numerical (C39)

If I were to manually search, I search for the header - "Fluence at spacecraft" (in B31) and check all cells in the surrounding columns (A and C) for the range of rows where energies are listed (A35 to A45).